# Order of bibliography entries?

Tags: bibtex

I'm writing a thesis and using Bibtex and the bibliography style alpha.
But of many authors have names beginning with the same 3 letters, and because alpha orders the entries according to the key, my bibliography ends up mixing all authors. For example

[Mil53] Miller 1953

[Mil55] Milhouse 1955

[Mil60] Million 1960

[Mil73] Miller 1973

[Mil98] Million 1998

[Mil03] Milhouse 2003
Is there a way I can change this ?

Thank you!

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! To avoid any confusion over *which one* of several authors whose names start with a certain three-letter combination may be meant in a given citation, you'll need to switch from the alpha style to an authoryear style